# AOSP x86_64 Emulator not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-source

I am using AOSP emulator for testing my code.
I downloaded the android10_release source code of AOSP in my pc.
Then used the following commands

```
source build/envsetup.sh

set_stuff_for_environment

lunch aosp_x86_64-eng

make -j6

emulator
```

now after running these commands I am successfully able to run emulator in my pc
OS of my pc is Ubuntu 18.04
I also installed many libraries for working with AOSP like jdk-8, python, curl, repo, git, and other stuff as per described in AOSP website

I am abe to see my emulator running in terminal by executing following commands

```
$ adb devices
```

List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

I am also able to install my apk in this emulator by executing following commands

```
$ adb install myapp.apk
```

and it gets installed and I can see it in emulator

Now coming to my question

**Why this emulator not showing in Android studio in devices
Even when I troubleshoot the adb connections in android studio it shows my emulator running but not showing in available devices.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or connect to it via network `adb connect localhost:5555` - port number is one higher than emulated device serial (in default case emulator-5554).
Then it is visible in Android studio and it works without issues.

solution that works for me (tried on two different machines):

```
$ cd aosp
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-10.0.0_r29
...
$ repo sync
...
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch sdk_phone_x86
$ m -j16
```

waiting for aosp to build

```
$ emulator &
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

$ adb connect localhost:5555
connected to localhost:5555
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
localhost:5555  device
```

[image]

start Android Studio (tested with 3.5.3 & 3.6.0)

In the devices list I see: "unknown Android SDK build for x86" with a little green dot next to it.

When I click on Run or Debug everything works

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and it is now showing two devices in adb devices command in terminal,
   

     $ adb devices
            List of devices attached
            emulator-5554 device
            localhost:5554 offline

 and it is showing as Unknown device in Android Studio but when I click on run it is showing error 

    Launching 'app' on Unknown Device.
    Installation did not succeed.
    The application could not be installed.
    Installation failed due to: 'device offline'

Comment: Do you have logcat output?
I'm using this setup quite consistently. Now I use aosp tag `android-10.0.0_r29`, I did built my image with `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64` and  I'm using `Android studio 3.5.3`
Sometimes android studio needs several tries to install or start debugging the app but the stock sdk mages have the same issues

Comment: How logcat output helps even the device is showing as offline?
I tried your answer and it is showing unknown device in Android Studio as offline

Comment: It will be good if you provide a complete working solution, otherwise delete your answer because it is not working

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, I am surprised to see that I followed your answer and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after doing a lot of research I got to know that if I want to use Emulator of AOSP in Android Studio so I need to follow this guide
Sharing AVD system images for others to use with Android Studio

Follow these instructions to share your AVD system images with others. They can use your AVD system images with Android Studio to develop and test apps.

```
Make additional sdk and sdk_repo packages:

$ make -j32 sdk sdk_repo

This creates two files under aosp-master/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk_phone_x86:
    sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip
    repo-sys-img.xml

Host the file sdk-repo-linux-system-images-eng.[username].zip somewhere accessible to your users, and get its URL to use as the AVD System Image URL.

Edit repo-sys-img.xml accordingly:
    Update <sdk:url> to your AVD System Image URL.
    See sdk-sys-img-03.xsd to learn about other updates to the file.

Host repo-sys-img.xml somewhere accessible to your users, and get its URL to use as the Custom Update Site URL.
```

To use a custom AVD image, do the following in the SDK Manager:

```
Add the Custom Update Site URL as an SDK Update Site.

This adds your custom AVD system image to the System Images page.

Create an AVD by downloading and selecting the custom AVD system image.
```

This link is helpful for reference

[Create avd from AOSP to use in Android Studio and also share with others](https://source.android.com/setup/create/avd)

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  I was not able.
After running "make sdk sdk_repo", I get multiple zips for docs, sdk, tools, and the listed files.

When setting the repo address to "repo-sys-img.xml", image is not visible in the AVD manager.

Both the image and repo-sys-img.xml are accessible on my host...but nothing shows.

Comment: The 'accepted answer' seems to imply that the image is already on the machine which is hosting the debugging session and AndroidStudio.  My goal is to build the AOSP images on one machine and have them accessible to the entire team.  Am I missing something?  Have you been able to create a shared image repository on a remote host?

Comment: Well I not hosted it on any url but yes I shared the image files created and it worked on other machines too

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same result with an aosp_car_x86_64 target. I launched the normal make then make sdk sdk_repo. Then I hosted the system-images zip and repo-sys-img.xml file in a local http server. I added the URL to android studio mirrors list but I am not able to create the emulator device through AVD because the system image is not listed. I made some tests and I can see it only if I change the abi from x86_64 to arm_something in repo-sys-img.xml of course It doesn't work..

Has anyone experienced same issue? Do you have any clue?

Comment: It appears that the sdk:revision parameter in xml file was wrong.. It correctly works if I set it to 9 instead of 6