# How ro run emulator with aosp 10(Q) source code

Tags: android, build, android-source

I downloaded the aosp 10(Q)source code with
 `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-10.0.0_r40` ,
`repo sync`. To run emulator, i started building the code with `source build/envsetup.sh`. I was confused to select which lunch option to run emulator. Here are the lunch options present :

```
 1. aosp_arm-eng
 2. aosp_arm64-eng
 3. aosp_blueline-userdebug
 4. aosp_bonito-userdebug
 5. aosp_car_arm-userdebug
 6. aosp_car_arm64-userdebug
 7. aosp_car_x86-userdebug
 8. aosp_car_x86_64-userdebug
 9. aosp_cf_arm64_phone-userdebug
 10. aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-userdebug
 11. aosp_cf_x86_auto-userdebug
 12. aosp_cf_x86_phone-userdebug
 13. aosp_cf_x86_tv-userdebug
 14. aosp_coral-userdebug
 15. aosp_coral_car-userdebug
 16. aosp_crosshatch-userdebug
 17. aosp_crosshatch_car-userdebug
 18. aosp_flame-userdebug
 19. aosp_marlin-userdebug
 20. aosp_sailfish-userdebug
 21. aosp_sargo-userdebug
 22. aosp_taimen-userdebug
 23. aosp_walleye-userdebug
 24. aosp_walleye_test-userdebug
 25. aosp_x86-eng
 26. aosp_x86_64-eng
 27. beagle_x15-userdebug
 28. car_x86_64-userdebug
 29. fuchsia_arm64-eng
 30. fuchsia_x86_64-eng
 31. hikey-userdebug
 32. hikey64_only-userdebug
 33. hikey960-userdebug
 34. hikey960_tv-userdebug
 35. hikey_tv-userdebug
 36. m_e_arm-userdebug
 37. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
 38. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
 39. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
 40. poplar-eng
 41. poplar-user
 42. poplar-userdebug
 43. qemu_trusty_arm64-userdebug
 44. uml-userdebug
```

Please tell me which lunch option is used to run emulator in aosp Q.

Comment: See: [AOSP x86_64 Emulator not visible in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60035816/295004)

Answer (score 2):

According to Android documentation ([Android Emulator > Building AVD images](https://source.android.com/setup/create/avd#building_avd_images)),
you should choose `lunch sdk_phone_x86` or `lunch sdk_phone_x86_64`.

You should choose this option according to your machine's CPU architecture.
If you are using Ubuntu machine, use the command `lscpu` to check your CPU architecture in a terminal.
If it says `x86_64`, then choose `sdk_phone_x86_64` lunch option.
If you choose the lunch option like this, it would make Android images that run really fast on your machine.

But if you need to run system apps/system services/executables/libraries that are built only for arm or arm64 architecture, you can still build Android images for arm/arm64 and run them on your machine.
To build `arm64` images you can choose `sdk_phone_arm64` lunch option.
But running arm Android images on your x86 machine will be very slow.

You can see all the options you have for emulator like this :

```sh
$ cd <aosp_root_dir>
$ ls -l build/make/target/product/sdk_phone_*

# Output :-
# sdk_phone_arm64.mk
# sdk_phone_armv7.mk
# sdk_phone_x86_64.mk
# sdk_phone_x86.mk
```